# Wemos D1 / Witty Cloud D8 doesn't behave as expected

Tags: esp8266

When using D8 in the code doesn't work, nothing happens, but replacing `D8` with `15` works like a charm. And to test this I created the code below. I know that D8 has worked earlier, but I don't remember which version I was using at that time, but it was a yer or more ago.

Environment:

- Arduino IDE ver. 1.8.13
- ESP8266 board ver. 2.7.4
- Witty Cloud or my add on version to WeMos D1 (https://oshpark.com/shared_projects/r3NRvNjx)
- WeMos D1 R1 chosen in Board manager

---

```
// "Witty Cloud" test program

// A0 - LDR resistor
// D2 - Button
// D6 - Green LED
// D7 - Blue LED
// D8 - Red LED

// Constants won't change. They're used here to set pin numbers:
const int LDR = A0;
const int BUTTON = D4;
const int GREEN = D6;
const int BLUE = D7;
const int RED = D8;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(LDR, INPUT);
  pinMode(RED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GREEN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BLUE, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BUTTON, INPUT);
}


void loop()
{

  delay(1000);

  Serial.println("");

  Serial.print("LDR: ");
  Serial.println(analogRead(LDR));

  digitalWrite(RED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(BLUE, LOW);
  Serial.println("--- Red ---");

  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(RED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(GREEN, HIGH);
  Serial.println("--- Green ---");

  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(GREEN, LOW);
  digitalWrite(BLUE, HIGH);
  Serial.println("--- Blue ---");
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the core of your board? In wiring.c (i think) these makros should be defined. Are they defined with the pin number or the bit number in the port?

Comment: I actually found the error, check, https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/variants/d1/pins_arduino.h and found the row `static const uint8_t D8   = 0;` bummer

Comment: D1 R1 has different pin mapping then R2 and mini

Comment: Now I see my mistake, I chosed a "WeMos R1" and not "LOLIN(WEMOS) D1 Mini".... why has WeMos changed to LOLIN ?